# Swift 5 - How to use rate to show video in reverse mode

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

I have a uiview that contains avplayer asset. I want to control the way of how the video is played.

Moving forward is grate and run smoothly, but when I'm trying to play it on backwards with rate= -1 the video is jumpy and choppy..

Is there better practice of running video inside uiview on backwards?